# Add ALT tag to the array in displaying image gallery in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, text, alt

How would I go about adding an ALT tag for these images? Would I have to add the 

`$alt = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);`
to the array, and then add the `<?php echo $alt; ?>` when displaying the image?

```
  <?php /* 2 IMAGES DIVIDER */ ?>
    <?php if($divider_type == 'images'): ?>
    <section class='divider content gallery'>
        <?php 
        $images = array();
        foreach($section['images'] as $image_id => $image_url)
        {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, '900w');
            $image_details = get_post($image_id);
            $images[] = array('img_url'=>$image[0],'caption'=>$image_details->post_excerpt);
        }
        ?>
        <div class='gallery-half'>
            <figure>
                <img src='<?php echo $images[0]['img_url']; ?>'>
                <?php if($images[0]['caption'] != ''): ?>
                <figcaption><?php echo $images[0]['caption']; ?></figcaption>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </figure>
        </div><!--
        --><div class='gallery-half'>
            <img src='<?php echo $images[1]['img_url']; ?>'>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `wp_get_attachment_image()`? This handles the alt tag for you.

```
<?php /* 2 IMAGES DIVIDER */ ?>
<?php if ( $divider_type == 'images' ) : ?>
    <section class='divider content gallery'>
        <?php 
        $images = array();
        foreach ( $section['images'] as $image_id => $image_url ) : ?>
            <?php $image_details = get_post( $image_id ); ?>
            <div class='gallery-half'>
                <figure>
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, '900w' ); ?>
                    <?php if ( $image_details->post_excerpt ) : ?>
                        <figcaption><?php echo $image_details->post_excerpt; ?></figcaption>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </figure>
            </div>
       <?php endif; ?>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I modified the snippet slightly so it will loop through all the images in your $section['images'] and output the in a `.gallery-half` div with the figure element and caption if there is one.

Comment: Hi @Jrod, sorry for the late response. I just tried you code snippet and it doesn't show anything on the post anymore if I use it.

Comment: @im2shae Any errors? Can you provide a link to your project?

Comment: I figured it out! I've added this code '$alt = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);' to the "foreach" item, I've added ''alt'=>$alt' to the array items, and added this 'alt='<?php echo $alt; ?>'' for the image src output.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help guys! Jrod and @nanodanger, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_get_attachment_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/#source-code) too, which will get you the `img` html tag with the `alt` attribute. However, you were right, if you want to get the value yourself, you have to use `get_post_meta`. Actually the `wp_get_attachment_image` function does the same to access that data.

```
$default_attr = array(
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size_class size-$size_class",
    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true) )), // Use Alt field first
);
```